# Coffeescript/Javascript design pattern for loading dependent data sources in parallel

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, asynchronous, coffeescript

I have two (slow loading) data sources.  I can start working on data source 2 as soon as it's loaded, but need the data from both 1 and 2 to work on data from source 1. So I have some code like this:

```
$.get 'url2', (data2) ->
    $.get 'url1', (data1) ->
        # do stuff with data1 and data2
    # do stuff with data2
```

But, I want to load them in parallel, instead of sequentially (i.e. I don't want to wait for data source 2 to load before starting to load data source 1).

Are there any nice design patterns to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var one = $.get 'url1'
var two = $.get 'url2'
$.when(one, two).then #both
$.when(two).then #just two
```

use the new [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) from jQuery 1.5.

here your loading them both in parallel. And using the "promises" returned from `$.get` to run some function once they are ready.

Comment: Great idea.  Do you need the second `$.when`? And can't you just use `done` instead of `then` (which takes 2 - done/fail params)

Comment: @Amir the second when could be `two.done #just two` you need the first `$.when` so that the `#both` function only triggers when both are done

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper class like like this:

```
class DeferredExecution
    getExecuteFunc: ->
        (x...) =>
            if !@onExecFunc
                @args = x
            else
                @onExecFunc x...
    onExecute: (func) ->
        @onExecFunc = func
        if @args
            @onExecFunc @args...
            @args = null
```

And then you can simply do:

```
deferredFunc = new DeferredExecution()
$.get 'url1', deferredFunc.getExecuteFunc()
$.get 'url2', (data2) ->
    deferredFunc.onExecute (data1) -> # gets executed only after we get the data from url1
        # do stuff with data1 and data2
    # do stuff with data2
```